# Safari reopens last open tabs?

Tags: safari, macos

On Lion, if I quit Safari using  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then restart it, it reopens all tabs from last time.

In Preferences, I have set that new Windows open with an Empty Page, a setting that worked fine in Snow Leopard.

Is there a way to disable that nonsense? I can't seem to find a setting for this :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a new feature in Mac OS X Lion. See [here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#resume) (Resume).

You can disable this in `System Preferences > General` and untick the "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps, but will be system wide.

Another solution is to hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> when quitting,  the app will then not save the state.

Comment: The setting in can be overridden for individual apps with something like `defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false`.

Answer (score 4):

In case you didn't have the foresight to shut down with a special command, you can always hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when starting Safari (or any other Resume-able app) to prevent it from restoring the previous state.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> tip, another way to think about it: If you always close all your tabs (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) before you quit, there won't be any state to save. Then when you restart Safari, you'll get your preference of a blank page, home page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as per [this other answer to a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54856/9495), is is actually possible to disable resume on a per-app basis, forcing Safari to start with a new window and as such take your 'empty page' preference into account.