# Preview hangs no matter what I do

Tags: pdf, preview, performance, bug

This question is a sequel of [Preview hangs when I try to change a PDF](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/204683/58138) but unfortunately  it's getting bigger and bigger.

Each time I open a PDF I get the spinning wait cursor instead of the normal cursor...

Here's the list of all the actions I tried:

- Repair permissions
- Repair disk
- Removed preferences
- Delete the `Preview.app` bundle and put a working one from a friend of mine
- Followed this question's answers : [Preview hangs when opening any image or pdf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/152188/58138).

I'm kind of *lost* and I can't afford a clean install now, as I'm in a middle of a big project and it would take me way too much time.

Here's the spindump report (I've got like dozens of them):

```
Date/Time:       2015-09-14 11:49:26 +0200
OS Version:      10.10.5 (Build 14F27)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  21

Command:         Preview
Path:            /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
Version:         8.0 (859.21)
Build Version:   1
Project Name:    Preview
Source Version:  859021000000000
PID:             1100

Event:           spin-lite
Duration:        3.80s (process was unresponsive for 2 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           39 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro8,2
Active cpus:     8

Fan speed:       3991 rpm

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  39  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13769) [0x7fff9602a5c9]
  39  NSApplicationMain + 1832 (AppKit + 12868) [0x7fff8aa07244]
  39  -[NSApplication run] + 594 (AppKit + 551667) [0x7fff8aa8aaf3]
  39  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346 (AppKit + 593496) [0x7fff8aa94e58]
  39  _DPSNextEvent + 978 (AppKit + 596139) [0x7fff8aa958ab]
  39  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71 (HIToolbox + 205099) [0x7fff898af12b]
  39  ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179 (HIToolbox + 205294) [0x7fff898af1ee]
  39  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235 (HIToolbox + 206191) [0x7fff898af56f]
  39  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 328 (CoreFoundation + 465912) [0x7fff95cffbf8]
  39  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368 (CoreFoundation + 524416) [0x7fff95d0e080]
  39  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23 (CoreFoundation + 524583) [0x7fff95d0e127]
  39  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 71 (QuartzCore + 118553) [0x7fff87516f19]
  39  CA::Transaction::commit() + 390 (QuartzCore + 58286) [0x7fff875083ae]
  39  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 253 (QuartzCore + 58909) [0x7fff8750861d]
  39  CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 381 (QuartzCore + 73643) [0x7fff8750bfab]
  39  CABackingStorePrepareFrontTexture + 54 (QuartzCore + 194238) [0x7fff875296be]
  39  CABackingStoreGetFrontTexture(CABackingStore*) + 92 (QuartzCore + 126308) [0x7fff87518d64]
  39  _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 597 (libdispatch.dylib + 46423) [0x7fff93250557]
  39  semaphore_wait_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 70938) [0x7fff8717d51a]
 *39  semaphore_wait_continue + 0 (kernel + 1353536) [0xffffff800034a740]

  Binary Images:
         0x1083c8000 -        0x10858afff  com.apple.Preview 8.0 (859.21)         <9054F13F-6533-303C-8854-C37DDEE165CC>  /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
      0x7fff8716c000 -     0x7fff87189fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.40.9)     <16AD15EF-3DAE-3F63-9D26-26CCE1920762>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
      0x7fff874fa000 -     0x7fff876aafff  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.10 (361.19)     <F815B60E-75E3-3263-BE93-27A49882CF58>  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
      0x7fff8987d000 -     0x7fff89b82fff  com.apple.HIToolbox 2.1.1 (758.7)      <E3129A67-BDF9-333D-9C9C-A95C8F0EF71C>  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
      0x7fff8aa04000 -     0x7fff8b585fff  com.apple.AppKit 6.9 (1348.17)         <E485D56D-3E72-34B7-99BB-BFDEE2D07BF5>  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
      0x7fff93245000 -     0x7fff9326ffff  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4)            <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0>  /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
      0x7fff95c8e000 -     0x7fff96026fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.9 (1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff96027000 -     0x7fff9602afff  libdyld.dylib (353.2.3)                <CFBBE540-D503-3AFC-B5D6-644F1E69949B>  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
 *0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80009fffff  kernel (2782.40.9)                     <58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4>  /System/Library/Kernels/kernel
```

---

What can I do now to fix this boring issue?

Comment: Not a fix, but a temporary solution: you can open most PDFs and Images in Safari.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes but I can't do annotations :(

Comment: Same issue? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/204683/131198

Comment: @mtklr nop, I've fixed this one