# Preview freezes whenever I try to edit and save a pdf

Tags: pdf, preview, performance

Preview always freezes (beachball) whenever I try to modify and save a .pdf. I've tried resetting the preferences for Preview (as per [Preview hangs when opening any image or pdf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152188/preview-hangs-when-opening-any-image-or-pdf?rq=1)) and have also tried resetting the PRAM and SMC.

Initially I noticed the problem when I was trying to add bookmarks and save the file, but I tested doing other modifications (highlighting, adding text, etc) and get the same result.

One weird thing I've noticed is that I first started getting this problem a few weeks ago but it was only intermittently happening. Sometimes it would allow me to modify the file and save it, other times it would freeze. But now it freezes every time I try to save the file.

And just for clarification, the file freezes once I go to save the file.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Does it have problems with graphic image files, e.g. .jpg, png, etc.? Does it have problems saving a graphic image file as a .pdf and or once saved as a .pdf then modify the .pdf and saved again as a .pdf?

Comment: Using El Capitan. It doesn't have problems with image files. I tried saving an image file as a pdf, and I'm able to make modifications to that pdf and save it just fine. I tried both annotating the image converted to pdf with shapes/text as well as adding a bookmark and no problems. I seem to experience this freezing issue only with native pdf files.

Comment: I was having this same exact issue, but it disappeared at some point in the public beta cycle. I'm not sure what version of El Captain you're running, but try upgrading to 10.11.2, which was just released this past week. 
App Store-> Updates

Comment: I have never had this problem before. But it has happened to me just now. Spinning rainbow wheels. I'm not doing anything different as far as I can tell.